# Crawling with "npm crawler"

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

For example i what to crawl description of Node.js modules from [npmjs.org](http://www.npmjs.org).
but this code doesn't work. and how it made this with jQuery, but not with [jsdom](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom) module.

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;
var crawler = new Crawler({
   "maxConnections":10,
});

crawler.queue([{
"uri":"https://npmjs.org/package/crawler",

"callback":function(error,result) {
    console.log("description:", window.$("p.description").text());
    }
}]);
```

Comment: How i can get text from https://npmjs.org/package/crawler <p class="description"> this text </p> and show it in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code exists too early.  Add a setTimeout on the last line to give enough time for your code to complete.

then call process.exit() from your callback function.

the crawler callback takes 3 parameters, the 3rd one being jQuery, so you probably use something like so:

```
"callback":function(error,result,$) {
  console.log("description:",$("p.description").text());
}
```

Comment: this module give by default 60000 milliseconds. the problem in dom traversing with jsdom